# CentOS 6, FTP settings lost after single user mode

Tags: linux, centos, ftp, command-line-interface

I recently put my server into single user mode with init 1. After I did that, I ran telinit 3, to try and get out of single user mode. It seemed to do the trick, however, now I cannot get back in with FTP access that was working previously. Any idea how to re enable FTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you enabled the FTP service to start on boot?

Run this command to set it:

```
chkconfig vsftpd on
```

Comment: I ran the command but I am not receiving any output

Comment: You won't - but if you do 'chkconfig |grep ftp' it should list the runlevels and an on or off status like this:    `vsftpd          0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off`